# I want \eqref to show (1.1), not (Equation 1.1)

Tags: equations

I am not LaTeX savvy, and I have juggled between a couple different template files.

My old, preferred template used

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amscd,amssymb,epsfig}
```

but I need to use this thesis template, which was not set up to be math friendly as far as I can tell, and so I added the packages mentioned above, as well as `amsmath`.

So the document displays equation references (using `\eqref`) as `(Equation 1.1)` when I want it to say `(1.1)`, for example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We don't know which template you're using, so it's quite difficult to say how you can remove the unwanted part.

Comment: use `graphicx` rather than `epsfig` (for any document written after 1993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine `\p@equation` as follows should resolve your problem.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@equation}{}
\makeatother
```

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{uicthesi} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@equation}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq: myeq}
F(x) = x^2
\end{equation}

\eqref{eq: myeq}
\end{document}
```

Before adding those lines:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: didn't work. I assume it's because I'm using some documentclass written by someone else. Should I provide the file(s)?

Comment: It would be better if you could.

Comment: My file uses: \documentclass{uicthesi}, then in the file uicthesi.cls, the only place 'equation' is mentioned is the following chunk of code:    
\def\p@equation{Equation~}
\def\theequation{\ifabseqnumbering\arabic{equation}
\else\thechapter.\arabic{equation}\fi}        ....So any idea how to properly edit this to get the desired effect? thanks

Comment: Do not change the cls file, just add the following lilnes: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@equation}{}
\makeatother` (an example is in edited version of the answer).

Comment: Hope it will resolve your problem!